# Set a default Financial Type when adding New Contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, financial-types

When I add a New Contribution, the Financial Type is required, but it is not preselected.

I would like to set a specific Financial Type as a defualt so it is already selected in the Financial Type dropdown when I click on New Contribution.

Is there a setting for this somewhere? I looked thru all the Admin menus but could not find one.

Thanks

EDIT:

I accepted the answer below about using a hook, but also posted a more detailed answer here:
[How to create a custom extension/module (with an example)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42359/how-to-create-a-custom-extension-module-with-an-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any such setting to set by default financial type on backend new contribution form.

However you can set it default programatically to a specific FT using buildform hook by calling $form->setDefault(['financial_type_id' => 1]); or JS.

It would be nice to have a config where you could set the default financial type to be so that you don't need to hard code in php/js

Comment: ok I am still new to CiviCRM so will have to investigate how to use a buildform hook.

Comment: Can the buildfrom hook be used on the default New Contributions page, or do I need to create a new custom form to use this?

Comment: Nope you don't need to

Comment: Ok so maybe I was not clear, but I am asking how do I call/use a buildform hook?

Comment: Ok, so I was actually looking for an answer of "how do I call buildform hook" ... Can it somehow be used on default New Contributions page? If yes, how? Or do I need to create a custom extension that will call the buildform hook for me?

Comment: Hooks need to be implemented via extensions or modules or plugins. Yes, you will need to create an extension and implement the buildform hook

Comment: Ok I figured out how to create an extension module in order to implement the hook: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42359/how-to-create-a-custom-extension-module-with-an-example

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Entity Templates](https://civicrm.org/extensions/entity-templates) extension to set up templates of contribution defaults. There can be a few tricks, but if you're willing to update the templates via API you can customize quite well (e.g. set receive_date: null to still have it default to today).