# Redirecting a profile page to somewhere else using hook

Tags: wordpress, profile, forms

I am using the buildForm hook, and when a specific profile page is loaded, I am checking to see if one specific user is logged in.

If that user is logged in, then I want to redirect the page somewhere else.

Is there a way to redirect the page from the buildForm hook (or maybe another hook)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the buildForm hook, you can check for the specific form/page you are looking for and then use **CRM_Utils_System::redirect** to redirect.

```
if ( $formName == 'CRM_Profile_Form_Edit' && $form->getVar('_gid') == 15 ) {
  //Redirect profile form that has gid = 15
  CRM_Utils_System::redirect("https://google.com"); // Redirect to another URL
}
```

This thread shows you how to use the buildForm hook: [How to create a custom extension/module (with an example)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42359/how-to-create-a-custom-extension-module-with-an-example)

Comment: I also came across this `CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->pushUserContext("https://google.com");` but I can not figure out how to use it.